# Tensorflow error in Jupyter notebook

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

After having installed tensorflow on Ubuntu 16.0 on AWS,
by using :

```
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow=1.2.1
```

When typing on terminal SSH :

```
ipython
import tensorflow as tf
tf.__version__
```

It returns 1.2.1 and everything is fine.

But, when this code is run on Jupyter Ipython notebook 
launched from same python install (anaconda),
I got this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-b6f7b46cc0dd> in <module>()
      1 import tensorflow as tf
----> 2 tf.__version__

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute '__version__'
```

Don't understand how this error can come over since the python distribution
is the same.

Is there a way to check the install of Tensorflow ?

EDIT:
This post https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3369
shows it might be related to sudo access to some folders.... when installed.
TBD

Comment: Could you explain more about your issue, please? For example, are you using GPU or CPU-only version? How did you install Tensorflow? etc. We aren't inside your head and we are unable to access your system. :P Besides, you should first read the Github issues like [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3369)

Comment: thx you very much, probable sudo on folder....

Comment: In Jupyter, after `import tensorflow as tf`, can you print the value of `dir(tf)` and add it to your question? I suspect that the problem is a different `PYTHONPATH` between the two instances of Python.

Comment: I am getting the same issue. I'm running a jupyter notebook from a conda environment.

Comment: okay I think I found the issue in my case. I installed jupyter notebook outside of my conda environment. So I deactivated the environment, uninstalled jupyter then activated again and installed jupyter inside my environment.